# Why does ADOX GetPermissions return 0 for an Access Form with Open/Run group permission set?

Tags: forms, ms-access, permissions, adox

Here's the scenario:

1. I have an Access 2003 (.MDB) database with User Level Security
2. I have a group G and a form F
3. Through "User and Group Permissions" dialog box, I explicitely set Open/Run permission (and only that) for group G on form F
4. I log in as user U (a member of group G) and can open the form F
5. In VBA I set an ADOX.Catalog variable cat to the current database and expect that the following call return something like adRightExecute (i.e.: 0x20000000); but it returns 0 (the last parameter is the GUID that designates Forms):
   `cat.Groups("G").GetPermissions("F", adPermObjProviderSpecific, "{c49c842e-9dcb-11d1-9f0a-00c04fc2c2e0}")`

I googled the issue in whatever creative search method I knew and was surprised that this case has not been addressed during the two decades that ADO is around!... So probably I am doing something wrong.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could give me a hint.

UPDATE:

- Having the following situation:
  [image: Permissions of Group G for Form F]
- And the following function:

```
Function GetPermissionsGroupForm(groupName As String, formName As String) As Long

    Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
    
    Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    GetPermissionsGroupForm = _
        cat.Groups(groupName).GetPermissions( _
            formName, _
            adPermObjProviderSpecific, _
            "{c49c842e-9dcb-11d1-9f0a-00c04fc2c2e0}")

End Function
```

- `GetPermissionsGroupForm("G", "F")` returns 0 (equally with ADOX 2.8 and 6.0)

UPDATE 2:

For information, the structure of ADOX Permissions (Long) is:

| BIT | Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 0x00000001 | NOT USED |
| 01 | 0x00000002 | NOT USED |
| 02 | 0x00000004 | NOT USED |
| 03 | 0x00000008 | NOT USED |
| 04 | 0x00000010 | NOT USED |
| 05 | 0x00000020 | NOT USED |
| 06 | 0x00000040 | NOT USED |
| 07 | 0x00000080 | NOT USED |
| 08 | 0x00000100 | `adRightDrop` |
| 09 | 0x00000200 | `adRightExclusive` |
| 10 | 0x00000400 | `adRightReadDesign` |
| 11 | 0x00000800 | `adRightWriteDesign` |
| 12 | 0x00001000 | `adRightWithGrant` |
| 13 | 0x00002000 | `adRightReference` |
| 14 | 0x00004000 | `adRightCreate` |
| 15 | 0x00008000 | `adRightInsert` |
| 16 | 0x00010000 | `adRightDelete` |
| 17 | 0x00020000 | `adRightReadPermissions` |
| 18 | 0x00040000 | `adRightWritePermissions` |
| 19 | 0x00080000 | `adRightWriteOwner` |
| 20 | 0x00100000 | NOT USED |
| 21 | 0x00200000 | NOT USED |
| 22 | 0x00400000 | NOT USED |
| 23 | 0x00800000 | NOT USED |
| 24 | 0x01000000 | NOT USED |
| 25 | 0x02000000 | `adRightMaximumAllowed` |
| 26 | 0x04000000 | NOT USED |
| 27 | 0x08000000 | NOT USED |
| 28 | 0x10000000 | `adRightFull` |
| 29 | 0x20000000 | `adRightExecute` |
| 30 | 0x40000000 | `adRightUpdate` |
| 31 | 0x80000000 | `adRightRead` |

I desperately tried all NOT USED bits and some combinations of the defined ones in order to set the `Open/Run` permission through `SetPermissions` ... No success!

Comment: Does the user or group need the right to read the form object's permissions? (`adRightReadPermissions`)

Comment: @HansUp No. Just to open the form as in an OpenForm statement